# How to add a class to meta box

Tags: metabox

When adding a metabox, i.e.:

```
add_meta_box( 
    'metabox_id',
    'Metabox Title',
    'my_metabox_callback',
    'page',
    'normal',
    'low', 
    array( 'foo' => $var1, 'bar' => $var2)
);
```

how do I add a `class` to it for css styling? I'd like to avoid having to call each `id` in the style rule for metaboxes that contain elements having the same style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class to the markup you are generating in the callback.

Comment: simple, as there's no built-in way to do this yet. i'll just wrap my metabox content in a `class`d `div`. thanks, @KDM

Answer (score 17):

Let's say you want a class for the excerpt box. Then you can do:

```
add_filter('postbox_classes_post_postexcerpt','add_metabox_classes');

function add_metabox_classes($classes) {
    array_push($classes,'another_class');
    return $classes;
}
```

With this method you need to add a filter for every box u need to add a class for. The filter is applied in the function postbox_classes in wp-admin/includes/post.php

In general the hook is `postbox_classes_{$page}_{$id}` where `$page` is the page identifier (e.g. 'post' for posts and (presumably) 'custom-post-type' for posts of type 'custom-post-type'). `$id` refers to the ID of the metabox, automatically assigned for 'default' metaboxes or specified in `add_meta_box`.

DOCS: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/postbox_classes_page_id/

Comment: this is awesome. but i'd have to admit it'll be much simpler if i just wrap my metabox output in a `class`d `div`. thanks so much for the answer, though @offroff you rock.

Comment: +1. Just added the general hook. I've not look closely at the source code, but I believe the `$page` variable, at least for post-edit screens, is the post type.

Comment: Yup can confirm when working on a custom post type that you need to supply the post type in place of {$page} - postbox_classes_posttype_metaboxid