# How to add a class to meta boxes (to customize them in CSS)?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have an situation: I just can't figure out how to add classes to some meta boxes.
I read these post [from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49773/how-to-add-a-class-to-meta-box), I tried this solution, but it did not work as I wanted.
Is there a way to add classes (to customize them in CSS) to meta boxes?
For example in this case:

```
  array(
    'label' => 'a name',
    'desc'  => 'description',
    'id' => 'id_x',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array('Bad', 'Good', 'Excellent'), /* HERE I WANT A CLASS FOR EACH THIS GUYS (to customize them in CSS) */
    'std' => "
    ),
```

I want that the HTML to look like this:

```
<span class="bad">Bad</span>
<span class="good">Good</span>
<span class="excellent">Excellent</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer given in your link is perfectly correct, you set it this way :

```
add_filter( 'postbox_classes_{post_type_name}_{metabox_id}', 'add_metabox_classes'  );

function add_metabox_classes($classes) {
  array_push($classes,'your_class');
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: So, I must add this filter in "function.php" and change this: "post_type_name" and "metabox_id", right? Just all?

Comment: and 'another class' to your class too.

Comment: How should be 'another_class'? I do not know what to write in "another_class". Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: If you want to use CSS class, replace `your_class` with your custom class and then style it.

Comment: `{post_type_name}` and `{metabox_id}` are example values, use the actual values in their place.. (without the curly quotes).

Comment: I did so, but I don't know why I don't achieve my scope. The filter now looks like this: add_filter( 'postbox_classes_test_id_x', 'add_metabox_classes' ); function add_metabox_classes($classes) { array_push($classes,'test'); return $classes; } . Is that correct or not?

Comment: @Blanka I guess you do not have that metabox for post type "test"... For regular Posts, put "post" instead of "test" ;)